# Alternative way of showing $A \subset B$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof

Consider two arbitrary subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, say $A$ and $B$ that aren't necessarily connected (here, I mean connected as in interligated, not in a mathematical sense) in any way possible.

Usually, when one wants to prove that $A \subset B$, what one does is to pick an arbitrary element $a \in A$ and shows that $a \in B$. My question is very simple: can we also prove that $A \subset B$ by proving that for any element $x \notin B$, it follows that $x \notin A?$

My intuition tells me that the answer should be yes, since I believe this a simple way to prove $A \subset B$ by contrapositive.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What does "interligated" mean?  As to your question:  Yes, that is the contrapositive and it's therefore equivalent to the original.

Comment: Looks good. Maybe draw a diagram to make it clear.

Comment: The implication $\text{not}(Q)\implies\text{not}(P)$ is called the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of the implication $P\implies Q$. They are logically equivalent, so proving one proves the other.

Comment: Presumably, "interligated" $\to$ *interrelated*.

Comment: It's the contrapositive: assume that for each $x \notin B$, it is true that $x \notin A$. Now, let $y \in A$ be arbitrary. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $y \notin B$. Then by hypothesis, $y \notin A$, which contradicts the hypothesis that $y \in A$. They're equivalent.